# Start a python Flask script from react.js frontend

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, flask, fetch

I have a python flask backend script and reactjs frontend.

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'no-cors'
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((json) => {.....})
    })
```

[this fetch will call each time a button will click].
this is working fine when i am running the python script from spyder or command and it is running on port 5000.
Now i want to run the python script directly from reactjs and fetch json data and not from command prompt or spyder. Is it possible to do that

Comment: Not sure what you mean by running python script directly from reeactjs. Can you elaborate on this.

Comment: Python can't be run in the browser, it's run on the server. Browsers can't execute Python scripts, those are meant to be run on the back end. What _specifically_ are you trying to do?

Comment: I meant to say that without running the python script from spyder can i run it (python-server) from react js directly

Comment: @Jayce444 i have a device that will send data when connected to pc locally. so everything should be running locally that time. To prevent the complexity to start the server locally from user end can user do it everything from frontend (like starting python when clicking a submit button)?

Comment: @shamikbasu no. Like I said, React (and all other Javascript code/libraries) are run in the browser on the *client* side. Your Python scripts are run on the *server* side. You can't execute a Python script from React code on the client side. If feasible, you can translate the functionaly of the Python script into browser-friendly Javascript and run it on the client side, but that's your best bet. You can't run Python in the browser

Comment: thanks for your response. i am working on it right away